# How do I add a border and shadow (or marker) to the head of my animated circle?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, svg

So I'm using this [component](https://github.com/georgealexiou/React-Native-Health-Rings/blob/main/components/HealthRings/Ring/Ring.tsx), and I'm trying to figure out a way to make the ring overlap with itself when it overfills (exceeds 100%), but to indicate that we need a border and shadow for wherever the head of the animated ring is. I've converted the code into JavaScript, so we need to do this in JavaScript for React Native.

```
    <Svg
      width={scaledWidth}
      height={scaledHeight}
      viewBox={viewBox}
      style={{ position: "absolute" }}
    >
      <Defs>
        <LinearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <Stop offset="0%" stopColor={gradientEndColor} />
          <Stop offset="100%" stopColor={gradientStartColor} />
        </LinearGradient>
      </Defs>
      <G rotation={-90} originX="90" originY="90">
        <Circle
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r={radius + 5} 
          stroke="black" 
          fill="transparent"
          strokeWidth={11}
        />
        <Circle
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r={radius}
          stroke={bgColor}
          fill="transparent"
          strokeWidth="19"
        />
        <AnimatedCircle
          cx="50%"
          cy="50%"
          r={radius}
          stroke="url(#gradient)"
          fill="transparent"
          strokeWidth="19"
          strokeDasharray={circleCircumference}
          strokeDashoffset={strokeDashoffset}
          strokeLinecap="round"
        />
      </G>
      {customIcon(radius)}
    </Svg>
```

I've tried making a circle that creates a ball and follows the end of the animated circle, not sure how to do that though. Also I've tried to create a marker for strokeLinecap, but I don't think it supports that.

Basically I'm trying to get this to function exactly like the Apple Activity Rings on the watch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there are no fancy solutions, it is just hard work making it seam that the circle is overlapping itself.

In this example (for each circle/meter) each is made of three circles. The middle one is the meter itself. The stroke dashdarray change value until it is a full circle. From there on the circle is just rotated. To make it appear that the meter overlaps itself there is a circle under the meter and over the meter. They have the same color, so it seams that they are one, and that they are one with the meter appearing under the gradient of the top circle.

To make the drop shadow only appear in "the front" of the meter there is a mask with a circle that is a bit longer than the meter.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let newval = parseInt(e.target.value);
  let rotateAll = (newval > 360) ? newval - 360 : 0;
  let rotateMask = (newval > 180) ? newval + 90 : -90;
  rotateMask = (newval > 270) ? 0 : rotateMask;
  let rotateMeter = (newval > 240) ? 45 : 0;

  let circle = document.getElementById(`circle${e.target.name}`);
  let maskcircle = document.querySelector(`#mask${e.target.name} circle`);

  circle.querySelector('.meter').setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${newval - rotateAll - rotateMeter} 360`);
  maskcircle.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${newval+5} 360`);
  circle.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${rotateAll})`);
  circle.querySelector('.under').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${rotateMask})`);
  circle.querySelector('.over').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${rotateMask})`);
  circle.querySelector('.meter').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${rotateMeter})`);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #111;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

lable {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <lable>Red: <input name="red" type="range" min="0" max="720" value="20" /></lable>
  <lable>Green: <input name="green" type="range" min="0" max="720" value="20" /></lable>
  <lable>Blue: <input name="blue" type="range" min="0" max="720" value="20" /></lable>
</form>
<svg height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" stroke-width="11.5" stroke-linecap="round">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x="-50" y="-50" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="1" />
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="lg01" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="maskred">
      <circle stroke="white" r="44" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="25 360"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="maskgreen">
      <circle stroke="white" r="32" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="25 360"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="maskblue" x="-60" y="-60" width="200" height="200" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle stroke="white" r="20" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="25 360"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask04">
      <rect transform="translate(10 -15) rotate(35)" fill="url(#lg01)" width="50" height="55"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask05">
      <rect transform="translate(10 -15) rotate(35)" fill="url(#lg01)" width="50" height="45"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask06">
      <rect transform="translate(10 -15) rotate(35)" fill="url(#lg01)" width="50" height="38"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <g transform="translate(50 50) rotate(-90)">
    <circle stroke="Tomato" r="44" opacity=".4" />
    <circle stroke="MediumSeaGreen" r="32" opacity=".4" />
    <circle stroke="SkyBlue" r="20" opacity=".4" />
    <g id="circlered" mask="url(#maskred)">
      <circle class="under" transform="rotate(-90)" stroke="red" r="44" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="15 360"/>
      <circle class="meter" stroke="Tomato" filter="url(#shadow)" r="44" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="20 360" />
      <circle class="over" transform="rotate(-90)" mask="url(#mask04)" stroke="red" r="44" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="55 360" stroke-dashoffset="-19" />
    </g>
    <g id="circlegreen" mask="url(#maskgreen)">
      <circle class="under" transform="rotate(-90)" stroke="ForestGreen" r="32" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="20 360"/>
      <circle class="meter" stroke="MediumSeaGreen" filter="url(#shadow)"  r="32" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="20 360" />
      <circle class="over" transform="rotate(-90)" mask="url(#mask05)" stroke="ForestGreen" r="32" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="55 360" stroke-dashoffset="-25" />
    </g>
    <g id="circleblue" mask="url(#maskblue)">
      <circle class="under" transform="rotate(-90)" stroke="DodgerBlue" r="20" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="28 360"/>
      <circle class="meter" stroke="SkyBlue" filter="url(#shadow)" r="20" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="20 360" />
      <circle class="over" transform="rotate(-90)" mask="url(#mask06)" stroke="DodgerBlue" r="20" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="55 360" stroke-dashoffset="-38" />
    </g>  
</svg>
```